# Run as Administrator in the startup

Tags: c#, startup, administration

hey I'm trying to launch an app on the startup I have always done it just fine by using this code :

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
if (rkApp.GetValue("Folder Locker") == null)
{
    rkApp.SetValue("Folder Locker", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
}
```

But now when I do this:

```
requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"
```

to start as administrator the app doesn't start on the start up I need help I hope it would be a small problem and not a big deal.

Comment: Generally, normal applications shouldn't need admin rights, which is why UAC would prompt for them, when running an app - it may be better to consider an alternative approach, like running as a windows service, and doing any IPC as required

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/537101/198092  this question really belongs on SuperUser - and is a duplicate on SO and SuperUser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get an application to run at logon that will elevate and somehow bypass the UAC dialog. That would pretty much defeat the purpose of UAC.

Your options include:

- Accepting that the user will be prompted for elevation.
- Modifying your application so that it does not require elevation. If some operations require elevation, then start a new elevated process to perform those tasks
- Running your process as service in session 0 where UAC does not apply.